# How to use redis cluster with StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm looking for High Availability using [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis).
My first approach was attempting to use Redis Sentinel with no success due to the package's capabilities.

I have a 6-noded cluster (3 masters & 3 slaves) in Docker. My app is able to connect to these 3 masters BUT when I turn off or pause a master container, my application throws a **RedisTimeoutException** because it is not able to reach the node it was connected before.

This is the output of running `cluster nodes` command `before` pausing a master
[image]

This is the output of running `cluster nodes` command `after` pausing a master
[image]

This is the exception my app throws
[image]

Currently, I'm connecting to the 3 masters

```
private const string Host = "10.0.0.2:7000, 10.0.0.3:7001, 10.0.0.4:7002";

private static readonly ConnectionMultiplexer Connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Host);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using

```
    RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration(nodesList);
```

This will required to connect to Redis Cluser.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `RedisClusterConfiguration` in SE.Redis, and I have a hunch that I would have noticed... can you clarify where that is coming from?

Comment: This comes from Spring Redis

Comment: I think StackExchange.Redis does not have a RedisClusterConfiguration class.